# How to Kong EE Configuration for Multiple Services to reduce cost

Tags: kong, kong-ingress

I'm configuring multiple services in KONG CE, but in KONG EE it costs about 250$ per service per months( and we have 20 of them).

```
services:
  - host: service1.com
    name: service1
    port: 8000
    route: ...

  - host: service2.com
    name: service2
    port: 9000
```

To reduce the cost, the concept is to create a  logical route combining all logical components as a single route.
In order to decrease expenses. For instance, this could be achieved ??

```
services:
  - host: bulk_service
    name: service1
    port: 8000
    route: 
    route1: -> service1.com
    route2: -> service2.com
    route3: -> service3.com
```

How can I configure it in KONG?